# Converting partial bolding in RTF to HTML format

Tags: html, vba, excel, rtf

I'm still very new to Stack Overflow and Vba.

I'm trying to convert RTF formatted cells to HTML format using a macro, but ran into problem with execution time. The current method is based on looping through all characters in each cell is particularly slow.

The partial "Bold" formatted text are very problematic for manual conversion, since I don't know any other way of getting properties of them other than looping through all the characters.

Also, the strings stored are usually pretty long, causing long loops if multiple cells are selected at the same time.

Is there another quicker way to either get the style properties of a cell or convert the whole cell into HTML quickly?

Data pattern of bold text do not stay the same:
[image: Data Sample]

Code for current method(UDF Function found from another thread.)

```
Function fnConvert2HTML(myCell As Range) As String
    Dim bldTagOn, itlTagOn, ulnTagOn, colTagOn As Boolean
    Dim i, chrCount As Integer
    Dim chrCol, chrLastCol, htmlTxt, htmlEnd As String

    bldTagOn = False
    itlTagOn = False
    ulnTagOn = False
    colTagOn = False
    chrCol = "NONE"
    'htmlTxt = "<html>"
    htmlTxt = ""
    chrCount = myCell.Characters.Count

    For i = 1 To chrCount
    htmlEnd = ""
        With myCell.Characters(i, 1)
            If (.Font.Color) Then
                chrCol = fnGetCol(.Font.Color)
                If Not colTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
                    colTagOn = True
                Else
                    If chrCol <> chrLastCol Then htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font><font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
                End If
            Else
                chrCol = "NONE"
                If colTagOn Then
                    htmlEnd = "</font>" & htmlEnd
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
                    colTagOn = False
                End If
            End If
            chrLastCol = chrCol

            If .Font.Bold = True Then
                If Not bldTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<b>"
                    bldTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If bldTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
                    htmlEnd = "</b>" & htmlEnd
                    bldTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If .Font.Italic = True Then
                If Not itlTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<i>"
                    itlTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If itlTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
                    htmlEnd = "</i>" & htmlEnd
                    itlTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If .Font.Underline > 0 Then
                If Not ulnTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<u>"
                    ulnTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If ulnTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
                    htmlEnd = "</u>" & htmlEnd
                    ulnTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If (Asc(.Text) = 10) Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & htmlEnd & "<br>"
            Else
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & htmlEnd & .Text
            End If

        End With
    Next

    If colTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
        colTagOn = False
    End If
    If bldTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
        bldTagOn = False
    End If
    If itlTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
        itlTagOn = False
    End If
    If ulnTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
        ulnTagOn = False
    End If
    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</html>"
    fnConvert2HTML = htmlTxt

    htmlTxt = ""
End Function

Function fnGetCol(strCol As String) As String
    Dim rVal, gVal, bVal As String
    strCol = Right("000000" & Hex(strCol), 6)
    bVal = Left(strCol, 2)
    gVal = Mid(strCol, 3, 2)
    rVal = Right(strCol, 2)
    fnGetCol = rVal & gVal & bVal
End Function
```

Comment: I think it's pretty hard to write a parser that converts cell formatting into HTML (and too broad to ask here). This is just not what Excel is thought to be used for. Excel is not a database it is for calculating tables that's its strength. What you try is to abuse Excel for other things. But have a look if `PublishObjects` is something you can use: `ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, "C:\temp\test.html", "Sheet1", "A1", xlHtmlStatic).Publish` this publishes cell A1 of Sheet1 as `test.html` (probably not exactly what you want.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I am stuck with data sitting in excel files sadly, but this is potentially useful for other situations, so thank you for posting it. I could copy the HTML code back into excel from the webpage. Doubt it will cut down calculation time, but I guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: I doubt that copying the HTML code back would work, because it is using CSS for formatting color etc not just simple HTML. If this is something that has not to be done automatically but only once in a while consider using a third party tool like [ExtendOffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3593-excel-convert-cells-to-html-table.html) (there are several others) so you don't need to re-invent the wheel.